# Cannot kill gunicorn processes

Tags: django, unix, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I am using a digitalocean ubuntu 14.04 vps.  When I run

```
sudo lsof -i:9000
```

I get varying results such as

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn 23148 django    5u  IPv4  51019      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)
```

or

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn 23174 django    5u  IPv4  51179      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)
gunicorn 23175 django    5u  IPv4  51179      0t0  TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)
```

where the number of gunicorn processes varies from 0-4, even if I run lsof immediately after the previous attempt.  Simply running

```
pkill gunicorn
```

is failing, I believe because the PIDs are constantly changing (as shown above).  How can I kill these processes permanently?  If it makes a difference, I am user "root", and do not have a login for user "django"

Comment: Can't you do `sudo service gunicorn stop`? (Or I guess no `sudo` if you are already root)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lsof` will only show the child processes which are actually binding to the port. You need to kill the master process. If you start gunicorn with the `--pid` option you can give it a filename to store the PID of that process in, then you can kill it directly; if not you can get it from `ps|grep gunicorn`.

Even better, as elethan suggests in the comments, set up gunicorn as a service using whatever process manager exists on your system - systemd, upstart, supervisor, or whatever - and use that to start and stop it.

Comment: Great explaination, thanks.  Elethan's comment solved the problem, and your answer explains why.